# Script to Move Range Showing No Error but Not Executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Learning scripts by trial and error.  Please forgive probable ignorance in the question.  I want a script to move a specific range (but not the whole row) in the active sheet to be positioned above another range in the active sheet.  I want this move to take place upon edit and only when the text in column H is "C".  The script I have so far runs with no errors but does not affect any change.  Additionally, I would like this same thing to happen not only for row 4 but for rows 4-18.  I was simply going to copy successful lines multiple times and update range for each, but I am sure there is a better way?

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var rangetoWatch = ("F4:I4");
  var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
  var valueToWatch = "C";

  if (sheet.getName() == sheet && sheet.getRange() == range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && rangetoWatch.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

   sheet.getRange("F20:I").moveTo(sheet.getRange("F21"));
   sheet.getRange("F4:I4").moveTo(sheet.getRange("F20:I20"));

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone stumbles across this thread in the future... i finally figured out what I was trying to accomplish.  a sample script is below.

```
  function movedown(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var mini = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3);

  var columnNumberToWatch = 3;
  var valueToWatch = "C";

  if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

  sheet.getRange("A15:C").moveTo(sheet.getRange("A16"));
  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).copyTo(sheet.getRange("A15:C15"));
  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).clear({contentsOnly:true});

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.  But I did not find your explanation to be very clear.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  //next line not required if you want it to happen on all sheets
  if(sheet.getName()!='SomeSheetName'){return;}//keep the process from only happening on one sheet
  if(e.range.rowStart>=4 && e.range.rowStart<=18 && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.value=='C') {
    sheet.getRange(20,6,sheet.getLastRow(),4).moveTo(sheet.getRange(21,6));
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,6,1,4).moveTo(sheet.getRange(20,6,1,4));
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have included in original post that I want the same functionality to apply across multiple sheets in the same document.  So, would think to use .getActiveSheet, but have not been able to make that work.

Comment: And do you always want to copy Column F to Column I on every row where column H is "C" to F20? You don't need to worry about specifying activeSheet the activesheet will always be the one your editing.

Comment: Viewing the image linked below...  Each partial row within the red box (F4:I4) is set to conditionally format to pink and bold text when "C" is placed in the column H for that row.  I want a script that will also move those four cells to the top of the partial rows in the green box below (F20-I20) and bump current info down while clearing the original cells (F4-F20).  Lastly, I have multiple sheets within this spreadsheet that are formatted exactly the same and want it to execute onEdit for the active sheet.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/171CFMJKkE2OIShdwv_qTctUuj4A4UWJY/view?usp=sharing