# Replace cell value of a column with cell value from another column based on a condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Quite new to google sheets apps script. I need help to do the following:

1. when the value in column S changes to 'Review' > take values from column W for all rows in 'Review' > replace existing values in column L with values from column W.
2. Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut to execute it?
   Many thanks for looking into it!

The question is very similar to this one [Set Value Based on Another Cell's Value in the Same Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692293/set-value-based-on-another-cells-value-in-the-same-row?rq=3) but instead of changing column L to a set/specific value, I need to change it to the corresponding value from column W.

Comment: `Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut to execute it?` Please read [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13731589/1330560)

Comment: Your requirement includes `dragging a value down for the entire batch of rows I am working on`

Comment: Question: 1) might a user copy/paste a value to another cell? 2) are the values in this column other than "Review"? 3) why not use Data Validation to enable selection of "Review".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

- Copy and save this function in the Project editor of your spreadsheet.
- The answer assumes that your sheet name is "Sheet1" (line 14). You may need to change this.
- I have left a number of `Logger` statements in the script. If you wish, you can use these to clarify/confirm variable values at different stages of the script.
- the answer will work if:

  - text is entered in a single cell
  - text is dragged down several rows
  - text is copy/paste from one column to another

---

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get Event Objects
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRowStart = e.range.rowStart
  var editedRowEnd = e.range.rowEnd
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  var numRows = editedRowEnd-editedRowStart+1
  // test for editing a single cell or a range
  if(editedRowEnd !== editedRowStart || e.value == undefined){
    // end row <> start row, so dragged value, or copy/paste
    // the editedValue is in the row ABOVE the start row
    var editedValue = editedSheet.getRange((editedRowStart-1), 19).getValue()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: dragged or copy/paste: the edited value = "+editedValue)
    var sourceRange = editedSheet.getRange(editedRowStart,23,numRows)
    var targetRange = editedSheet.getRange(editedRowStart,12,numRows)
  }else{
    // edited a single column, event object available
    var editedValue = e.value
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: data entry single cell: the edited value = "+editedValue)
    var sourceRange = editedSheet.getRange(editedRowStart,23)
    var targetRange = editedSheet.getRange(editedRowStart,12)
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", edited rowStart = "+editedRowStart+", edited rowEnd = "+editedRowEnd+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", source range = "+sourceRange.getA1Notation()+", target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
  // Logger.log("Number of edited rows = "+numRows)

  // test for edit on sheet:"Sheet1", in Column:S(19) and value:"Review"
  if (editedSheetName !== "Sheet1" || editedCol !== 19 || editedValue !== "Review") {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: INVALID edit: sheet <> input &/or col <> 1 &/or value <>Review")
    return
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = Sheet1 & col = 19 & value =Review")
    // copy data from Column W (23) to column L9(12)
    if (numRows == 1){
      targetRange.setValue(sourceRange.getValue())
    }
    else{
      targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have another follow up question. That worked in the spreadsheet but I have run into another issue: it works when I change rows in S column to 'Review' one by one. However, when I change the first one and drag it down for the entire batch of rows I am working on, nothing happens. Could you have a look please?